# Cocos2d-x Chartboost Android Initialization strange error

Tags: android, cocos2d-x-3.0, chartboost

I'm using Cocos2d-x v3.2 with latest Chartboost android SDK v5.5.3.
I've done everything mentioned in the SDK Integration document for android but I have very strange error in logcat when my app runs.

This is my initialization code in onCreate()

```
//Init Chartboost
    Chartboost.startWithAppId(this, getString(R.string.chartboost_app_id), getString(R.string.chartboost_app_signature));
    Chartboost.setImpressionsUseActivities(true);
    Chartboost.setShouldRequestInterstitialsInFirstSession(false);
    Chartboost.setDelegate(cbDelegate);
    Chartboost.onCreate(this);
```

And the logcat shows up:

```
09-07 16:58:21.221: W/System.err(16168): java.lang.Exception: Chartboost Initialization error. Activity or appId or appSignature is invalid
09-07 16:58:21.222: W/System.err(16168):    at com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost$6.run(SourceFile:666)
09-07 16:58:21.222: W/System.err(16168):    at com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost.a(SourceFile:1129)
09-07 16:58:21.222: W/System.err(16168):    at com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(SourceFile:663)
09-07 16:58:21.222: W/System.err(16168):    at com.android.Main.preloadChartboost(Main.java:1078)
09-07 16:58:21.224: W/System.err(16168): java.lang.Exception: Chartboost Initialization error. Activity or appId or appSignature is invalid
09-07 16:58:21.224: W/System.err(16168):    at com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost$9.run(SourceFile:733)
09-07 16:58:21.224: W/System.err(16168):    at com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost.a(SourceFile:1129)
09-07 16:58:21.224: W/System.err(16168):    at com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost.cacheMoreApps(SourceFile:730)
09-07 16:58:21.225: W/System.err(16168):    at com.android.Main.preloadChartboost(Main.java:1079)
09-07 16:58:21.698: W/System.err(16168): java.lang.Exception: Chartboost Initialization error. Activity or appId or appSignature is invalid
09-07 16:58:21.698: W/System.err(16168):    at com.chartboost.sdk.Chartboost.onCreate(SourceFile:169)
```

Tell me please, what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of solutions, finally I figured out that issue caused because of caching ad at wrong place.

I previously called `Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);` at `init()` method. After moving `Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocation.LOCATION_DEFAULT);` to other place such as `onResume()`, this error flew away.

But I have no idea why the logcat says that the error occurs because of invalid appID or appSignature. Too weird!

Answer (score 0):

My issue for the invalid appID or appSignature was this missing required permission:

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE